# on click of radio button display images using jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview, google-web-designer

In a page I displayed all images with one category.

```js
  $("input[name$='pets']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#flowers" + test).show();
    });
 });
```

```html
    
<label>
<input type="radio" name="pets"  value="2"  id="radio-choice-0a">Pets
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio"  name="flowers" value="3"  id="radio-choice-0b">Flowers
</label>
```

Here is my options. when click on pet options pet images will diaplay. otherwise disable

Comment: Welcome to SO,That's not how Stackoverflow works, you need to show what you have tried so far, check this to understand it better http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what exactly is the issue  ?

Comment: I have tried and fixed it.thanks

Comment: cool post the answer and close this question :)

Answer (score 0):

$("input[name$='pets']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

```
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("#flowers" + test).show();
});
});
```

```js
 $("input[name$='pets']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#flowers" + test).show();
    });
 });
```